# Как залогиниться в чате?

Tags: поддержка, чат, аутентификация

Не понял как в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) залогиниться.

Там нужен какой-то отдельный акк на SE или можно как-то имеющимися аккаки на SO & ru-SO ограничиться?

P.S. Почему вопрос не запостить в виде без ссылки? Пишет что, мол, неформат заголовка...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы создаете учётную запись на любом из сайтов сети Stack Exchange (например, Stack Overflow на русском), у вас автоматически создается учётная запись на StackExchange.com. На сколько мне известно, для входа в чат используется именно она.

Если у вас не получается войти, пожалуйста, проверьте, что вы авторизованы на StackExchange.com

P.S. Скорее всего, вопрос не отправлялся из за того, что не проходил один из фильтров качества. Они достаточно прямолинейные для русского языка.

Comment: Что-то странное у меня было. Чрез гугловую учётку не входило. А сейчас потестил - всё работает. Наверное я что-то не так делал...

Answer (score 1):

Как это не удивительно, выяснилось, что логинился я там когда-то чрез лицоКнигу. Так и зашёл. А чрез google нет.